# What's the proper interpretation of the entity span start and end in the XML output for the Stanford NLP relation tagger

Tags: stanford-nlp

The XML output of the Stanford NLP tool, version 3.6.0, contains blocks like this for the relation extraction:

```
       <relation id="RelationMention-11">Located_In
          <arguments>
            <entity id="EntityMention-3">PEOPLE
              <span start="12" end="13"/>
              <probabilities/>
            </entity>
            <entity id="EntityMention-4">LOCATION
              <span start="17" end="18"/>
              <probabilities/>
            </entity>
          </arguments>
          ...
       </relation>
```

What's the proper interpretation of the span start and end? They're clearly indices into the token list of the sentence, but they don't correspond to the first and last tokens of the corresponding mention annotation. Here are the relevant tokens in the sentence above:

```
      <token id="12">
        <word>and</word>
        <lemma>and</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>66</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>69</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>CC</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="13">
        <word>Lazio</word>
        <lemma>Lazio</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>70</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>75</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>NNP</POS>
        <NER>PERSON</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="14">
        <word>provinces</word>
        <lemma>province</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>76</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>85</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>NNS</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="15">
        <word>in</word>
        <lemma>in</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>86</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>88</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>IN</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="16">
        <word>Long</word>
        <lemma>Long</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>89</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>93</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>NNP</POS>
        <NER>LOCATION</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="17">
        <word>Beach</word>
        <lemma>Beach</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>94</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>99</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>NNP</POS>
        <NER>LOCATION</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="18">
        <word>Island</word>
        <lemma>Island</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>100</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>106</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>NNP</POS>
        <NER>LOCATION</NER>
      </token>
      <token id="19">
        <word>and</word>
        <lemma>and</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>107</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>110</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>CC</POS>
        <NER>O</NER>
      </token>
```

My best guess is that the end offset of each relation is the token index of the head in the dependency structure that forms the argument, but I can't be sure.

UPDATE: Even more confused as I look further. The following sentence:

"John Kerry says Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu and Palestinian President Mahmoud Abbas are both being tested politically."

produces the following relations:

```
        <relation id="RelationMention-9">Work_For
          <arguments>
            <entity id="EntityMention-3">O
              <span start="8" end="9"/>
              <probabilities/>
            </entity>
            <entity id="EntityMention-4">PEOPLE
              <span start="11" end="12"/>
              <probabilities/>
            </entity>
          </arguments>
          ...
        </relation>
        <relation id="RelationMention-12">Work_For
          <arguments>
            <entity id="EntityMention-4">PEOPLE
              <span start="11" end="12"/>
              <probabilities/>
            </entity>
            <entity id="EntityMention-3">O
              <span start="8" end="9"/>
              <probabilities/>
            </entity>
          </arguments>
          ...
       </relation>
```

The relation it's finding is Work_For(Abbas, Palestine), basically, but it's finding it twice (one of which must be the wrong argument order), and it's pulling the label for the entity from a token that isn't even in the argument.

I've tested this in 3.7.0 beta and gotten the same behavior. Help!

UPDATE 2: I've finally gotten around to following Chris Manning's instructions on how to decode Google protocol buffers in Python, and here's what I get for the entities in the second example:

```
entity {
  objectID: "EntityMention-3"
  extentStart: 8
  extentEnd: 9
  type: "O"
  headStart: 8
  headEnd: 9
  headTokenIndex: 8
  corefID: "-1"
}    
entity {
  objectID: "EntityMention-4"
  extentStart: 10
  extentEnd: 12
  type: "PEOPLE"
  headStart: 11
  headEnd: 12
  headTokenIndex: 11
  corefID: "-1"
}
```

So, first answer: the span start and end are the head start and end, not the extent start and end.

Then, I went back to the original NER list and realized that the entity of type "O" has an NER label  "MISC", and then I realized that PEOPLE isn't an NER label. So, next answer: the types of the entities aren't the NER labels. They're coming from somewhere, not sure where - they're not coming from coref, because I didn't extract coref in my command, but they're clearly not expected to be the NER labels. This raises the additional question of where they **are** coming from, and what the label inventory is.

The final mystery is what's going on with getting two of the relations spanning the same interval. I've got to assume that this is something that the particular training regimen can't rule out as a possibility, but it's also possible that it's a decoding bug.

Comment: How are you creating those relations?  When I issue this command I get something fairly reasonable: java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner,depparse,mention,entitymentions,coref,kbp -file sample-sentence.txt

Comment: Here's my command line: java -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,relation -file snippet.txt. Thanks for replying, but I don't know what you mean by "fairly reasonable". I'd describe what I got as "fairly reasonable" given the expected performance of the relation tagger, but like I said in the post, I don't understand what the span start and end mean, since they don't correspond to the token index start and end of the corresponding entity mention.

Comment: So I've edited the post to reflect that I think I know what the index start and end are. But the label inventory is still mysterious to me, and I can't tell whether the duplicate relations are a bug or not.

Comment: Just to clarify, the "relation" module is sort of older and quasi-deprecated, whereas the "kbp" module is the brand new relation extraction module (in version 3.7.0).  I would advise using the "kbp" module, and when I look at its xml output the token indexes, etc...seem correct.

Comment: The relation labels for this new annotator are based on the KBP challenge: http://tac.nist.gov/2015/KBP/ColdStart/guidelines/TAC_KBP_2015_Slot_Descriptions_V1.0.pdf

Comment: I'm definitely going to add some documentation to our main site!

Comment: That would be great. Instructions on training it would be lovely as well.